# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle can't update doctrine database schema or clear cache

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to learn how to do registration with Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle. I was doing it step by step with the documentation provided in: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md But when I try to run the comman `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I get this error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                      
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Registration\BusinessBundle\Entity\BusinessUser" 
sub class of "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User". 
Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

If I run the command `php app/console cache:clear` I get the same error. I tried deleting cache folder manually but when I try to update doctrine schema, again same error appears.

my BusinessUser Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Registration\BusinessBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="business_user")
 */

class BusinessUser extends BaseUser
{
    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you put this question 2 times in stackoverflow, I copy and paste my answer:

Your Entity does not contain PHP docblock comments where your Doctrine Annotation is used.

Docblocks are startet with two asterisks, otherwise it's just a simple comment.

Change your current code

```
/*
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
 */
protected $id;
```

to

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
 */
protected $id;
```

Only with /** will annotations be recognized by Doctrine.

Check your other properties too.